# How to get transactions before a date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to get the count of data which were present before a given date. In my case November 1 2015. I tried adding filter as below: where ct is the creation time of format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

```
    "filter": 
     {

        "range":
         {
           "ct":
            {
              "lte":"2014-11-01",
              "gte":"2000-01-01"
            }
         }
     }
```

I also tried another filter as shown below :

```
   "aggregations": {
     "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "ct",
            "ranges": [
                { "to": "2015-11-02" }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
```

But no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What results do you get and how are you sending your query?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am sending query via sense plugin of chrome. I am getting results which are having creation time even in 2016 which is not the expected result.

Comment: Please specify mapping of `ct` field. Is it date??

Comment: Are you using GET or POST?

Comment: I am using GET. And ct is of type date. Sorry for not specifying it in my question

Comment: You should always use POST when sending a payload. Try it and tell us if you see any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use group by to get your desire result. Please try this one:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_date": {
      "range": {
        "field": "ct",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": "2015-06-18T12:28:25.013Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```